# Rtabmap tf issue with ekf

Tags: robot-localization, rtabmap-ros, ros-humble

I am trying to use Rtabmap with filtered odometry from ekf (robot_localization) I used the turtlebot demo, but changed the topics for my robot. It works, the map looks alright, but there is a constant error message:

```
[rtabmap-1] Error:   TF_SELF_TRANSFORM: Ignoring transform from authority "Authority undetectable" with frame_id and  child_frame_id "map" because they are the same
[rtabmap-1]          at line 209 in ./src/buffer_core.cpp
[rviz2-3] Error:   TF_SELF_TRANSFORM: Ignoring transform from authority "Authority undetectable" with frame_id and  child_frame_id "map" because they are the same
[rviz2-3]          at line 209 in ./src/buffer_core.cpp
[rtabmap_viz-2] Error:   TF_SELF_TRANSFORM: Ignoring transform from authority "Authority undetectable" with frame_id and  child_frame_id "map" because they are the same
[rtabmap_viz-2]          at line 209 in ./src/buffer_core.cpp
```

There is also a similar error message from the EKF node and navsat transform node:

```
[ekf_node-5] Error:   TF_SELF_TRANSFORM: Ignoring transform from authority "Authority undetectable" with frame_id and  child_frame_id "map" because they are the same
[ekf_node-5]          at line 209 in ./src/buffer_core.cpp
[navsat_transform_node-6] Error:   TF_SELF_TRANSFORM: Ignoring transform from authority "Authority undetectable" with frame_id and  child_frame_id "map" because they are the same
[navsat_transform_node-6]          at line 209 in ./src/buffer_core.cpp
```

I launched rtabmap with:

```
ros2 launch rtabmap_launch rtabmap.launch.py visual_odometry:=false frame_id:=base_link odom_topic:=/odometry/filtered args:="-d" use_sim_time:=true rgb_topic:=/camera/image_raw depth_topic:=/camera/depth/image_raw camera_info_topic:=/camera/camera_info approx_sync:=true qos:=2 rviz:=true
```

There are no error messages when I launch it with odom_topic:=odom.

Rtabmap is not publishing to /odometry/filtered as far as I can tell.

```
ros2 topic info /odometry/filtered
Type: nav_msgs/msg/Odometry
Publisher count: 1
Subscription count: 3
```

view frames doesn't show anything unusual either, though the same error appeared on trying to run it.

```
Error:   TF_SELF_TRANSFORM: Ignoring transform from authority "default_authority" with frame_id and  child_frame_id "map" because they are the same
         at line 209 in ./src/buffer_core.cpp
```

It still works, but I'd like to know where this error is coming from if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include your config files?